# Sprite quads & depth testing correctly in OpenGL ES 2

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am trying to render 2D (flat) sprites in a 3D environment using OpenGL ES 2. The way I create each sprite is pretty standard: I create a quad consisting of two triangles, and I map the texture onto that. Everything works fine, except I noticed something strange: when depth testing is turned on (which it should be in 3D mode), the corners of my sprites are painted using the background color.

The easiest way to show this is by illustration:

[image: Image comparison with and without depth testing]

When I turn off depth testing (on the left) it looks fine, but when I turn it on (on the right) you can see the green sprite's rectangle overlapping on top of the yellow sprite. They both use the same code, the same PNG file, the same shader. Everything is the same except depth testing.

I'm hoping someone might know a way to work around this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you can do is alpha testing. Basically your texture has to have an alpha value of 0 where it should be transparent (which it may already have). Then you configure alpha test like e.g.

```
glAlphaFunc(GL_GREATER, 0.5f);
glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);
```

This way every pixel (or better fragment) with an alpha value <= 0.5 will not be written into the framebuffer (and therefore not into the depth buffer). You can also do the alpha test yourself in the fragment shader by just discarding the fragment:

```
...
if(color.a < 0.5)
    discard;
...
```

Then you don't need the fixed-function alpha test (I think that is the reason why it is deprecated in modern desktop GL, don't know about ES).

**EDIT:** After looking into the ES 2.0 spec, it seems there is no fixed-function alpha test any more, so you will have to do it in the fragment shader like written above. This way you can also make it dependent on a specific color or any other computable property instead of the alpha channel.

Comment: I did look into the GL_ALPHA_TEST idea before I posted, and as you also found out, it's not available. I tried your shader test, it looks like a good idea, but for some reason it's having no effect.

Comment: @Mike Strange, did you make sure you texture has an alpha of zero at the transparent parts (if using alpha for comparison)? And you're also using an RGBA texture (instead of just RGB)?

Comment: My mistake. :) I was doing the test on the color uniform. What I needed to do was -- lowp vec4 color = Color * texture2D(Texture, TexCoordOut); if (color.a < 0.5) discard; gl_FragColor = color; -- It works great now, thanks a million!