# Change part of sprite rendered below another to alpha

Tags: libgdx

I am using LibGDX. Is it possible to achieve this behavior with [SpriteBatch](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.html) and [Sprites](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.html)? The blue sprite has alpha around and ends by that thin blue border.

The red sprite is rendered first, then the blue one, and there is a hole in the red one depending on alpha from blue, pattern background is there just for demonstration

I want exactly what this guy does not (enabling GL_DEPTH_TEST does not work for me)
[Sprite quads & depth testing correctly in OpenGL ES 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067492/sprite-quads-depth-testing-correctly-in-opengl-es-2)

[image]

Comment: you can do this using spritebatch and shape renderer.

Comment: this example is only a simplified version of my problem, i have to use spritebatch since i am rendering sprites, not geomtery

Comment: Are you creating texture(image) for sprite at run time?

Comment: There's no trivial way to do it. Might be possible with FBOs or custom shaders if your needs are simple enough. Is there ever more than one of the red type of Sprite on screen, and if so, can they overlap each other? Are the interior edges of the blue sprites always rectangular?

Comment: @Tenfour04 yes, there are atleast 3 red sprites overlapping randomly, alpha area of blue sprite can be totally random

Comment: @arv no, I am using texture atlas

Comment: And blue sprites' alpha should "cut through" all red sprites at once but not cut through other blue sprites?

Comment: it doesnt matter, there will be only one blue sprite

Comment: Desired effect is like this (with GL_DEPTH_TEST enabled) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067492/sprite-quads-depth-testing-correctly-in-opengl-es-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
package com.mygdx.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;

public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
    SpriteBatch batch;
    Texture bg, red, blue;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        bg = new Texture("bg.png");
        red = new Texture("red.png");
        blue = new Texture("blue.png");
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); //we have to clear depth buffer

        //BG
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(bg, 0, 0);
        batch.end();

        Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_DEPTH_TEST); //1. TRICK
        batch.begin();
        Gdx.gl.glDepthMask(true); //2. TRICK (after batch.begin())
        batch.draw(blue, 220, 220); //reversed rendering order (blue first! can you tell me why?)
        batch.draw(red, 200, 200);
        batch.end();
        Gdx.gl.glDisable(GL20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose () {
        batch.dispose();
        bg.dispose();
        red.dispose();
        blue.dispose();
    }
}
```

[image]